# Update from CTE issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am updating from a cte but got this common error
`The multi-part identifier "t.newfips" could not be bound.` I know how to handle this error in other cases, but I don't know how in this case.

My query

```
with t as (
select * from FIPSModificationsBEA t1
inner join [BEAtoFIPS] t2
on cast(t1.newfips as varchar) = concat(t2.statefips,t2.CountyFIPS)
)
update [BEAtoFIPS]
set statefips = left(t.oldfips, 2) , countyfips = right(t.oldfips, 3)
from [BEAtoFIPS] t2
where concat(t2.statefips, t2.countyfips) =  t.newfips
go
```

I checked the query by the following query

```
with t as (
select * from FIPSModificationsBEA t1
inner join [BEAtoFIPS] t2
on cast(t1.newfips as varchar) = concat(t2.statefips,t2.CountyFIPS)
)
select newfips from t
go
```

This query works. Thus, I am confused. Why the latter one works but the former one does not? Aren't they essentially the same in structure? What's wrong with the former one?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring `varchar` without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should always provide a length for all `varchar` or `nvarchar` variables/parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just update the cte:

```
with t as (
select * from FIPSModificationsBEA t1
inner join [BEAtoFIPS] t2
on cast(t1.newfips as varchar) = concat(t2.statefips,t2.CountyFIPS)
)
update t
set statefips = left(t.oldfips, 2) , countyfips = right(t.oldfips, 3)
go
```

Otherwise join to the `cte`

```
with t as (
select * from FIPSModificationsBEA t1
inner join [BEAtoFIPS] t2
on cast(t1.newfips as varchar) = concat(t2.statefips,t2.CountyFIPS)
)
update t2
set statefips = left(t.oldfips, 2) , countyfips = right(t.oldfips, 3)
from [BEAtoFIPS] t2
  inner join t
    on concat(t2.statefips, t2.countyfips) =  t.newfips
go
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `UPDATE` query doesn't have a `FROM` entry for the CTE `t` (but your `SELECT` does, which is why it works).

One way to think of CTEs is like a temporary view visible only to one query. So what you have is (sort of) like this:

```
Create View t (...) 
as 
(
select * from FIPSModificationsBEA t1
inner join [BEAtoFIPS] t2
on cast(t1.newfips as varchar) = concat(t2.statefips,t2.CountyFIPS)
)
go

update [BEAtoFIPS]
set statefips = left(t.oldfips, 2) , countyfips = right(t.oldfips, 3)
from [BEAtoFIPS] t2
where concat(t2.statefips, t2.countyfips) =  t.newfips
go
```

It's probably more obvious in this example that `t` is not actually defined anywhere in the `UPDATE` query.

To fix it, you need to `JOIN` to the view to tell it how it's connected to the query:

```
update [BEAtoFIPS]
set statefips = left(t.oldfips, 2) , countyfips = right(t.oldfips, 3)
from [BEAtoFIPS] t2
join t
on concat(t2.statefips, t2.countyfips) =  t.newfips
go
```

The query with the CTE needs to look exactly the same - `JOIN` to the CTE and specify how it relates to the rest of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't joined your CTE in your update query so `t` isn't assigned.

Try this:

```
WITH tempData AS (
    SELECT * FROM FIPSModificationsBEA t1
    INNER JOIN [BEAtoFIPS] t2
    ON CAST(t1.newfips as varchar) = CONCAT(t2.statefips,t2.CountyFIPS)
)

UPDATE t2
SET statefips = LEFT(t.oldfips, 2), 
    countyfips = right(t.oldfips, 3)
FROM [BEAtoFIPS] AS t2
INNER JOIN tempData AS t
    ON t.newFips = concat(t2.statefips, t2.countyfips)
```

However you should be able to do this without the cte at all:

```
UPDATE b
SET statefips = LEFT(m.oldfips, 2), 
countyfips = RIGHT(m.oldfips, 3)
FROM [BEAtoFIPS] AS b
INNER JOIN FIPSModificationsBEA AS m
    ON CAST(m.newfips as varchar) = CONCAT(b.statefips,b.CountyFIPS)
```